# Как вывести данные о Git в java?

Tags: java, git, maven, gitlab

имеется репозиторий GitLab, а также Maven + java (Со всеми файлами spring, включая property и тд). Как при запуске программы можно вывести название ветки, hash commit? Без запуска через консоль с параметрами

Comment: ветки, hash commit чего? При запуске какой программы должны выводиться эти данные? Без запуска через консоль какой программы и с какими параметрами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Без запуска через консоль с параметрами

В [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-B%3A-%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Git-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-Libgit2) есть глава о встраивании гит, в частности упомянута библиотека [LibGit2](https://libgit2.org/)

Для этой библиотеки существует множество оберток(binding) для других языков, в частности для Java это [Jagged](https://github.com/ethomson/jagged).